# @0.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --inline --hot` angular 7

Tags: angular, webpack

I get this error when I execute:

```
npm start
```

[image]

This started after I upgraded `webpack`.

Comment: What version did you upgrade webpack to?

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the `*debug.log` file?

Comment: @Haem I can not remember

Comment: @Haem How do I downgrade?

Comment: @betontalpfa nothing relevant. Looks like the error in the screenshot I provided.